# SQLAlchemy query many to many relationship for set equality

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have two classes and junction table between

```
class Foo(Model):
   ...
   bars = db.relationship("Bar", secondary=foo_bar, backref="foos")
   
class Bar(Model):
   ...

foo_bar = db.Table("foo_bar",
  Column("foo_id", ...),
  Column("bar_id", ...)
)
```

How can I query for Foo objects that have an exact set of bar objects as stored in some list. For example

```
bars = [bar1, bar2, bar3] # list of bar objects from earlier query
matching_foos = Foo.query.filter(???).all() # should only be the Foo objects with a relationship to only bar1, bar2, and bar3
```

Things that I've tried that don't work (error)

```
Foo.query.filter(
   Foo.bars.contains(bar),
   Foo.bars.contained_by(bar),
)

Foo.query.filter_by(
   Foo.bars = bars
)
```

Comment: Are the bars for a given  foo unique (i.e.  foo1 cannot reference bar1 twice?

Comment: yes foo1 will never reference bar1 twice.